# How do I sort a 2d array of ints in Kotlin using sortedBy?

Tags: kotlin, generics

new in Kotlin stuck on something basic.

I have this 2d array:

```
val intervals: Array<IntArray> = arrayOf(
    intArrayOf(1, 3),
    intArrayOf(15, 18),
    intArrayOf(8, 10),
    intArrayOf(2, 6),
)
```

by how do I sort this by the first element of each sub-array.

the output should be:
(1,3); (2,6); (8,10); (15,18)

I tried this but I am not clear of the syntax and did not work.

```
intervals.sortedBy { it[0] }
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is exactly how you do that, the only thing you could change would maybe be to do `it.first()` instead of `it[0]`, but that might just be preference. Of course, if you don't know the values of your array and it might have any internal array with 0 elements, then you should also check for that.

The reason I think you believe it is not working, is because you are expecting it to sort in place. There are 2 different methods you can use: [sortBy {}](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by.html) and [sortedBy{}](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html). The first sorting the initial array, and the latter returning a new sorted list.

As for not understanding the syntax, I'd recommend reading [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/) (that would have also shown the difference between the 2 functions). But to make it a bit more understandable, you could name the `it` param.

```kotlin
//this creates a new list
val newList = intervals.sortedBy { internalArray -> internalArray.first() }
```

or

```kotlin
//this sorts the given array
intervals.sortBy { internalArray -> internalArray.first() }
```